# How can we access context of an application in Robolectric?

Tags: robolectric

Actually, I need to get a response of an API call, for that I required `Context`.

Answer (score 245):

**Update.**

Just use for version 1.x and 2.x:

```
Robolectric.application;
```

And for version 3.x:

```
RuntimeEnvironment.application;
```

And for version 4.x:

- add to your `build.gradle` file:

  ```
  testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.0.0'
  ```
- retrieve the context with:

  ```
  ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()
  ```

Comment: Did you put @RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class) for your tests?

Comment: Yeah.. I added... but still it return null

Comment: One has to use the build variant "unit tests" too to make Robolectric tests working. This could be why RuntimeEnvironment.application is null in previous comments

Comment: I have done all of what you've mentioned and still get null. Anything else I might be missing?

Comment: `@RunWith` should be enough

Comment: Also make sure that you don't use `RuntimeEnvironment.application` in static code (like methods annotated with `@BeforeClass`) as Robolectric will probably not be initialized at that point and the value will be `null`.

Comment: Also this causes the application to bleed between tests .. which may not be desirable

Comment: And if it is still null ?

Comment: Then you probably forgot to use `RobolectricTestRunner`

Comment: RuntimeEnvironment.application does not seem to have access to the resources of the application

Comment: What kind of resources?

Comment: This works for me with Robolectric 3.5.1: `ShadowApplication.getInstance().applicationContext`

Comment: Actually there is no code example added for the question, but I guess that you are trying to access the context inside one of your under-test classes, and apparently the context which you try to access is not the one from Robolectric.

Please make sure that you are using the same context from `RuntimeEnvironment.application` in all of your classes which you are testing and if the problem still exists, please update the question with code examples.

Comment: Why testImplementation and not androidTestImplementation?

Comment: @Trevor at the time writing it the Robolectic was used only for running tests on JVM

Answer (score 27):

You can use

```
RuntimeEnvironment.application
```

Comment: in RoboElectric 3.0, Roboelectric.application no longer exists, so this is probably the best answer

Answer (score 20):

Add

```
testImplementation "androidx.test:core-ktx:${deps.testrunner}"
```

And use:

```
private val app = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()
```

Comment: import androidx.test.core.app.ApplicationProvider

Comment: val appContext = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()

Comment: This is the correct answer with the latest Robolectric. Other methods mentioned here are deprecated or removed.

Answer (score 19):

Use this:

```
Robolectric.application
```

Answer (score 8):

For the latest Robolectric 4.3 as of right now in 2019 `

> ShadowApplication.getInstance()

` and

> Roboletric.application

are both depricated. So I am using

```
Context context = RuntimeEnvironment.systemContext;
```

to get Context.

Answer (score 6):

To get application context you must do the following:

1. annotate @RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
2. RuntimeEnvironment.application.getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 3):

In some cases, you may need your app's context instead of the Robolectris default context.
For example, if you want to get your package name. By default Robolectric will return you `org.robolectric.default` package name. To get your real package name do the following:

build.gradle

`testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.2.1'`

Your test class:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config( manifest="AndroidManifest.xml")
public class FooTest {

@Test
public void fooTestWithPackageName(){
    Context context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext();
    System.out.println("My Real Package Name: " + context.getPackageName());
}

}
```

Make sure that in your Run/Debug Configurations Working directory is set to: $MODULE_DIR$
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Agree with answers of  @EugenMartynov and @rds ....

A quick example can be found at Volley-Marshmallow-Release

in NetworkImageViewTest.java

`//    mNIV = new NetworkImageView(Robolectric.application);
        mNIV = new NetworkImageView(RuntimeEnvironment.application);`

Volley link is available
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/marshmallow-release

you have to add dependencies in volley module in android studio as :

`dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.1.2'
}`

Answer (score 2):

This works for me with Robolectric 3.5.1: `ShadowApplication.getInstance().applicationContext`

Comment: Note that it looks like the 4.0 release will remove this method; better to stick with `RuntimeEnvironment.application` or  `RuntimeEnvironment.application.getApplicationContext()` if its working for you.

Answer (score 2):

As of [release 4.0-alpha-3](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/commits/robolectric-4.0-alpha-3) on July 21, they [removed](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/commits/robolectric-4.0-alpha-3/shadows/framework/src/main/java/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowApplication.java) `ShadowApplication.getApplicationContext()`. Stick with [`RuntimeEnvironment.application.getApplicationContext()`](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/master/shadows/framework/src/main/java/org/robolectric/RuntimeEnvironment.java) for any tests annotated with `@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)`.

As an aside, their [current guide](http://robolectric.org/using-qualifiers/) has an example of getting string resources using:

```
final Context context = RuntimeEnvironment.application;
```

(Note that the javadocs for [`RuntimeEnvironment`](http://robolectric.org/javadoc/latest/org/robolectric/RuntimeEnvironment.html) and [`ShadowApplication`](http://robolectric.org/javadoc/latest/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowApplication.html) currently reflect the non-alpha 3.x release.)

Answer (score 2):

First add the following to your `build.gradle`:

`testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.2.0'`

then use:

`ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext() as Application`

Answer (score 1):

It is safer to use `Robolectric.getShadowApplication()` instead of using `Robolectric.application` directly.

Comment: But what if I need to access some custom properties of my custom application? It seems that I can't get the real object from shadow application.

Comment: @DenisKniazhev Sorry I can't answer that for you. Shortly after we started using Robolectric we started using Travis as our CI, and they don't play nicely.

My guess is that you can either cast it to your application or you might need to make a custom runner to get access to it that way. Best of luck

Comment: Thanks, for now I have just stuck to `Robolectric.application`

Comment: **Robolectric.getShadowApplication()** is not available

Answer (score 1):

In your case I think you should be mindful of what it is you're actually testing. Sometimes running into issues of *untestable* code or seemingly untestable code is a sign that maybe your code needs to be refactored.

For an API call response you might not want to test the API call itself. It may not be necessary to test that it's possible to send/receive information from any arbitrary web service, but rather that your code *handles and processes your response in an expected manor.*

In which case it might be better to refactor the code you're trying to test. Break out the response parsing/handling to another class which accepts a simple `String` and do your testing *on that class* by injecting sample string responses.

This is more or less following the ideas of *Single Responsibility* and *Dependency Inversion* (The **S** and **D** in [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)))

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I know many others said this answer before and might already outdated

```
    when(mockApplication.getApplicationContext()).thenReturn(RuntimeEnvironment.application);
    when(mockApplication.getFilesDir()).thenReturn(RuntimeEnvironment.application.getFilesDir());

    sharedPref = RuntimeEnvironment.application.getSharedPreferences(KEY_MY_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    sut = new BundleManagerImpl(mockApplication,
            processHtmlBundle, resultListener, sharedPref);
```

I got null, because the when() part was AFTER the sut initialization. It might help some of you.

also I have the

```
@RunWith(CustomRobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class)
```

at the beginning of the class

Also

```
 when(mockApplication.getApplicationContext()).thenReturn(RuntimeEnvironment.application.getApplicationContext()); works
```