# How RobolectricTestRunner create a Robolectric.application?

Tags: android, robolectric, junit-runner

I need to customize the RobolectricTestRunner from Robolectric project, but I found a strange behaviour that I don't understand:

[RobolectricTestRunner](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/robolectric-2.2/src/main/java/org/robolectric/RobolectricTestRunner.java)
contains the `methodBlock` which calls 
`setUpApplicationState(bootstrappedMethod, parallelUniverseInterface, strictI18n, systemResourceLoader, appManifest, config);`
the method executes `setUpApplicationState` of [ParallelUniverse](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/robolectric-2.2/src/main/java/org/robolectric/internal/ParallelUniverse.java) class.

At line 146, `setupApplicationState` executes `application.onCreate();` 
When I debug the application, when I check the Robolectric.application value at line 146 I see that it's created successfully, but if I check the same value in the RobolectricTestRunner class, after the line: 220, Robolectric.application is null...
Why? it's a static value.. I can't understand that!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question:
parallelUniverse is created by calling the `sdkEnvironment.getRobolectricClassLoader()` which use a different classLoader: `AsmInstrumentingClassLoader`,  `RobolectricTestRunner` is part of a different classLoader, so I can't access to the same object

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this, if this might help you 
[How can we access context of an application in Robolectric?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13684094/how-can-we-access-context-of-an-application-in-robolectric/39225353#39225353)

And also consider answer by @EugenMartynov having 100+ upvotes

```
Just use for version 1.x and 2.x:

Robolectric.application;

And for version 3.x:

RuntimeEnvironment.application;
```

Hope this helps you....