# Robolectric 3.0-rc2 Hamcrest-core conflict

Tags: android-studio, robolectric, android-actionbaractivity

Hello I'm trying to get `ActionBar` Activity UnitTests going and I'm using **`Robolectirc-RC2`**, but when i try to sync my android studio I'm getting the following error/warning.
Warning:Conflict with dependency `org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core`. Resolved versions for app and test app differ.
Any idea how to resolve it?

```
repositories {
maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
mavenLocal()
mavenCentral()
```

}

```
dependencies {
// Unit testing dependencies
unitTestCompile('junit:junit:4.12') { // Prevent duplication conflicts
    exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
    exclude module: 'hamcrest-library'
    exclude module: 'hamcrest-integration'
}
unitTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1'
unitTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.1'
unitTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.1'
unitTestCompile 'com.squareup.assertj:assertj-android:1.0.0'
```

Comment: Try to change `unitTestCompile` to `testCompile`

Comment: now i'm getting the following error. Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations'. Resolved versions for app and test app differ.

Comment: Additionally i need to use robolectric for testing instead of default android testing.

Comment: Please read my comment about dependency scope

Answer (score 4):

ok the solution was to add the following code.

```
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy {
    force 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3'
}}
```

and then replace per [How can we access context of an application in Robolectric?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13684094/how-can-we-access-context-of-an-application-in-robolectric)
Just use for version 1.x and 2.x:

**Robolectric.application;**

And for version 3.x:

**RuntimeEnvironment.application;**

additionally replace

**Config(emulateSdk = 18, reportSdk = 18, manifest = "src/test/AndroidManifest.xml")**

with

**@Config(sdk = 18)**

Comment: I tried using resolutionStrategy without success (same error, different libs).  I was able to get it to compile simply by adding compile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3' just above adding the dependency in question - in this case Robolectric.  In my case it was for sendgrid

Answer (score 1):

Here is how we specify `Robolectric` in our projects:

```
   testCompile("org.robolectric:robolectric:${robolectricVer}") {
        exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
    }
```

Comment: I've made the changes above and now android studio can not find junit jar file and i'm getting some errors.  error: package org.robolectric.annotation does not exist import org.robolectric.annotation.Config;

Comment: It would be easy if you share your whole build.gradle file and project structure