# Resolved versions for app (1.1) and test app (1.3) differ

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, hamcrest

I'm beginner with android and gradle. I saw this error so I removed the hamcrest dependency from my module gradle but I still see the following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.
>
> > Conflict with dependency 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (1.1) and test app (1.3)
> >     differ.

This dependency is causing the problem:

```
compile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
```

app grade:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

module gradle (I have a single module):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.stavalfi.app1"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.0.0'
}//testImplementation



apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

What I have tried:

```
//testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile('junit:junit:4.12') { // Prevent duplication conflicts
    exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
    exclude module: 'hamcrest-library'
    exclude module: 'hamcrest-integration'
}
```

But I get the same error.

I also saw this solution but I don't know where to add the configurations exactly:

[Robolectric 3.0-rc2 Hamcrest-core conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30352553/robolectric-3-0-rc2-hamcrest-core-conflict)

And I don't see why I need to have this problem if I don't use hamcrest anyway.

Thanks!

Comment: Where did you get this dependency `com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1` and its version? Have you tried simply removing this dependency? (which I never seen before)

Answer (score 0):

add configuration.all below buildtypes.

**configurations.all {}**

```
 android {
            compileSdkVersion 26
            defaultConfig {
                applicationId "com.nfs.ui.notesapp"
                minSdkVersion 14
                targetSdkVersion 26
                versionCode 1
                versionName "1.0"
                testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            }
            buildTypes {
                release {
                    minifyEnabled false
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                }
            }


    configurations.all {
                resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.0.0'
            }

        }
```