# Testing Android Kotlin app - Mockito with Dagger injects null

Tags: android, mockito, kotlin, robolectric

I'm learning testing on Android with Mockito and Robolectric. I created very simple app in Kotlin with RxJava and Dagger2, using Clean Architecture. Everything works well on device, but I can't make my test pass. Here is my LoginPresenterTest:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner::class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig::class)
public class LoginPresenterTest {

    private lateinit var loginPresenter: LoginPresenter

    @Rule @JvmField
    public val mockitoRule: MockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule()

    @Mock
    private lateinit var mockContext: Context

    @Mock
    private lateinit var mockLoginUseCase: LoginUseCase

    @Mock
    private lateinit var mockLoginView: LoginView

    @Mock
    private lateinit var mockCredentialsUseCase: GetCredentials

    @Before
    public fun setUp() {
        loginPresenter = LoginPresenter(mockCredentialsUseCase, mockLoginUseCase)
        loginPresenter.view = mockLoginView
    } 

    @Test
    public fun testLoginPresenterResume(){
        given(mockLoginView.context()).willReturn(mockContext)
        loginPresenter.resume();
    }
}
```

LoginPresenter contructor:

```
class LoginPresenter @Inject constructor(@Named("getCredentials") val getCredentials: UseCase,
                                     @Named("loginUseCase") val loginUseCase: LoginUseCase) : Presenter<LoginView>
```

in `loginPresenter.resume()` i have:

```
override fun resume() {
    getCredentials.execute(GetCredentialsSubscriber() as DefaultSubscriber<in Any>)
}
```

And, finally, GetCredentials:

```
open class GetCredentials @Inject constructor(var userRepository: UserRepository,
                                     threadExecutor: Executor,
                                     postExecutionThread: PostExecutionThread):
                                    UseCase(threadExecutor, postExecutionThread) {

    override fun buildUseCaseObservable(): Observable<Credentials> = userRepository.credentials()

}
```

The problem is, that every field in `GetCredentials` is null. I think I miss something (I took pattern from this project: https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture), but I can't find what is it. Does anyone know what may cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a mock instance of `GetCredentials` (`@Mock var mockCredentialsUseCase: GetCredentials`) that's why you have `null`s in its fields. It's rarely a good idea to mock everything apart from the main class under test (`LoginPresenter`). One way to think of this is to divide the dependencies into [peers and internals](https://github.com/daryllxd/lifelong-learning/blob/master/programming/ruby/testing/growing-object-oriented-software-guided-by-tests.md#internals-vs-peers). I would rewrite the test to something like:

```
inline fun <reified T:Any> mock() : T = Mockito.mock(T::class.java)

@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner::class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig::class)
public class LoginPresenterTest {

    val mockContext:Context = mock()
    val mockLoginView:LoginView = mock().apply {
        given(this.context()).willReturn(mockContext)
    }
    val userRepository:UserRepository = mock() // or some in memory implementation
    val credentials = GetCredentials(userRepository, testThreadExecutor, testPostThreadExecutor) // yes, let's use real GetCredentials implementation
    val loginUseCase = LoginUseCase() // and a real LoginUseCase if possible
    val loginPresenter = LoginPresenter(credentials, loginUseCase).apply {
        view = mockLoginView
    }

    @Test
    public fun testLoginPresenterResume(){
        given(mockLoginView.context()).willReturn(mockContext)
        loginPresenter.resume();

        // do actual assertions as what should happen
    }
}
```

As usual you need to think about what you're testing. The scope of the test does not have to be limited to a single class. It's often easier to think of features you're testing instead of classes (like in [BDD](https://dannorth.net/introducing-bdd/)). Above all try to avoid tests like [this](https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture/blob/master/domain/src/test/java/com/fernandocejas/android10/sample/domain/interactor/GetUserListTest.java) - which in my opinion adds very little value as a regression test but still impedes refactoring.

*PS. Roboelectric add [helper functions for context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13684094/how-can-we-access-context-of-an-application-in-robolectric)*

Comment: Thank you for reply. I resolved this by creating `UseCaseTestClass`, which mocks `GetCredential` behaviour, so everything works good.