# Android Roboelectric test: null pointer in getting view id in Custom Toast

Tags: android, robolectric, android-toast

I have a Custom Toast class -

```
public static void makeToast(final Context context, String message) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_with_icon, null, false);

        TextView text = layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText(message);
        text.setTextColor(Color.RED);

        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast toast = new Toast(context.getApplicationContext());
                toast.setView(layout);
                toast.show();
            }
        });
    }
```

**I want to get the text in a Roboelectric test when this Toast is shown and assert it**, for which I'm using this -

```
var checkMessage = ShadowToast.showedCustomToast("Login failed. your credentials are not valid", R.id.text)
assert(checkMessage)
```

But that gives me a null pointer for `R.id.text`-

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
> org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowToast.showedCustomToast(ShadowToast.java:159)
> at
> in.novopay.novoloan.ui.login.data.LoginRepositoryTest.testLoginWithWrongCredentials(LoginRepositoryTest.kt:56)

Is my way of accessing the custom Toast layout correct?
Can there be a better way of asserting the custom Toast message ?

Comment: i don't want to make a custom toast. i want to unit test the custom toast that is already there

Comment: how about a decent [mcve] and actually show the code of showedCustomToast(...) ?

Comment: showedCustomToast is a pre made function from Roboelectric. not my function. Again. Im using Roboelectric to test my code. Im not trying to show a toast, im trying to run unit tests in roboelectric test runner

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong parameter sequence a

```
ShadowToast.showedCustomToast("Login failed. your credentialsare not valid", R.id.text)
```

you should use
 `ShadowToast.showedCustomToast(context,"Login failed. your credentials are not valid")`
and also you are passing  `R.id.text` which  integer value, not a `context`
...

Comment: I understand that but you are not passing the context to the function that is the error you should [check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13689162/14588625) this